# What i need edit to make user who i can select

Tags: php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id");   

while($UserInfo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $UserInfo['username'];
}
```

Here is simple code how i list all users. How to make, i can click each user and shows his profile page?

Answer (score 1):

assuming another script called `profile.php` you could do something like this.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id");   

while( $UserInfo = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
    echo "<a href='profile.php?username={$UserInfo['username']}'>{$UserInfo['username']}</a>";
}
```

The `profile.php` script should intercept and process the `$_GET` variable `username`, generate the required sql and display whatever.

Comment: Thanks. thats what i was searching.

Answer (score 0):

please put link inside the while loop.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id");   
while($UserInfo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<a href="user_profile.php?uid=',$UserInfo['username'],'">';
  echo $UserInfo['username'];
  echo '</a>';
}
```

**user_profile.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
  $user_id=$_GET['uid'];
  echo $user_id;
  //retrieve the user data with the $user_id by sql.
  //display the user information.
}
```